# adding all elements within division and append it jquery without touching html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm super new to coding and I'm not allowed to touch the html given.
I added the codes in js file and the ones that i comment out is the one that I added to append. But it is not working. The background does not follow the ones b4.
Is there another way for it be be simpler? I feel that it is the wrong way as the code is too bulky.[this is what i have after i added the codes in js, the ones not commented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uppgZ.png)
[this is what happen when i added the commented code in js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbzQg.jpg)

[this is the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1iWM.png)

what am I doing wrong or how can i better my codes?

```css
#contentimages
{
    background-color: grey;
}

.col
{
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;  
    background-color: #d7dadb;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:10px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.col p
{
    text-align: left;
}
.imageCS{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.imageCS:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```js
var _img3 = document.getElementById('img3');
var newImg3 = new Image;
newImg3.onload = function() {
    _img3.src = this.src;
}
newImg3.src = 'https://www.suss.edu.sg/images/default-source/card/home_grad2-optimize.tmb-373_373.jpg?sfvrsn=413c2ef7_1'; 
    
    
 var para = document.createElement("H3");
var node = document.createTextNode("Graduate Programmes");
para.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("image3");
element.appendChild(para); 
 var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("SUSS graduate programmes are structured to hone graduates, giving them a competitive edge as they progress in their careers");
para.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("image3");
element.appendChild(para);    

/*
var newHeading = " <H3>Law Programmes</H3>";
    var newParagraph = document.createElement("p");
    newParagraph.innerHTML = "Our primary focus is to train and produce lawyers for the practice of law in Singapore, particularly in the areas of Criminal Law and Family Law";
    var newImage4 = new Image;
    newImage4.class="imageCS";
    newImage4.src='https://www.suss.edu.sg/images/default-source/card/home_law2-optimize.tmb-373_373.jpg?sfvrsn=80b4ca55_1 ';
    $("#contentimages").append(newHeading, newParagraph, newImage4);
    
    */
```

```html
div id="contentimages">
            <div id="image1" class="col">
            <img id="img1" class="imageCS"/>
            <H3></H3>
            <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="image2" class="col">
            <img id="img2" class="imageCS"/>
            <H3></H3>
            <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="image3" class="col">
            <img id="img3" class="imageCS"/>
            <H3></H3>
            <p></p>
            </div>   
        </div>
```

Comment: Hey Welcome to SO community, please provide us the noting input and expected output so that people can understand the question easily and provide you the best solution on it.

Comment: Thank you. okay ive edited and added the picture in. Is this how I should do it?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function for you to create a profile card. Call the function `createProfileCard(imageurl,image4Heading,image4Desc)`
with the required parameters to create a new card.

```
function createProfileCard(imageurl,image4Heading,image4Desc){
 let parentNode = document.getElementById("contentimages");
 let element = document.createElement("div");
 element.classList.add('col');
 element.innerHTML = `<img src='${imageurl}' class="imageCS"/><h3>${image4Heading}</h3><p>${image4Desc}</p>`;
 parentNode.appendChild(element);  
}
let image4url = "https://www.suss.edu.sg/images/default-source/card/home_law2-optimize.tmb-373_373.jpg?sfvrsn=80b4ca55_1";
let image4Heading = "Graduate Programmes";
let image4Desc = "Our primary focus is to train and produce lawyers for the practice of law in Singapore, particularly in the areas of Criminal Law and Family Law";
    
createProfileCard(image4url,image4Heading,image4Desc);
```

Refer to the expected output here -> https://codepen.io/askannan/pen/RwoZyyK